# How to display parent/child model data in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have invoice as the parent model and invoice details as the child model. 
Like to display the parent/child details in the Invoice model **admin**.
Target is to list Invoices and related invoice details in admin.

Invoice admin to list invoices

```
Invoice 1:
Invoice 2:
```

Once on invoice admin, click on an invoice and list Invoice detail in a list_display in admin change page

```
Invoice 1:
 -details 1 ..... 
 -details 2 ....
```

ps. I know this is possible using a view and template. But I am not there yet.

Comment: Did you do the Django tutorial? Inline forms, which is what you want, are covered in [part 7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial07/).

Comment: @DanielRoseman. Yes I know how to do inline form. But what I want to achieve is the not inline but in the admin change page.. Perhaps I not asking the right question.  Not sure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to use the list_filter to filter by related details.